# Module not found on path for interface table module

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am getting the following error

> Module not found on path 'GPSSim.satellite[0].interfaceTable' defined by par 'GPSSim.satellite[0].wlan[0].interfaceTableModule' -- in module (inet::InterfaceEntry) GPSSim.satellite[0].wlan[0] (id=51), during network initialization

There are a lot of code but i will show the ones that i believe is important. If more code is required do let me know, thanks!

**GPSSIM.ned** This file is the network file

```
network GPSSim
{
    parameters:

        int numOfSats; // Number of satellites

    submodules:

        satellite[numOfSats]: GPSSatellite {
            parameters:
                @display("p=505.835,100.085;r=10,,#707070;i=device/satellite_l");
        }

}
```

**GPSSatellite.ned**

```
module GPSSatellite extends StandardSatellite
{
    submodules:

        gpsApp[numGpsApps]: <default("GPSApp")> like IGPSApp {  //default("UdpApp")
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,284,row,60");
        }
}
```

**StandardSatellite.ned**

```
module StandardSatellite extends Satellite
{
    parameters:
        @node; //because of MobilityBase initialization'
        @networkNode();
        int numRadios = default(1); 
        **.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
        //wlan[*].mgmt.typename = default("Ieee80211MgmtAp");
        //wlan[*].interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceEntry"));
        //wlan[*].mgmtType = default("Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc");  // use adhoc management

    submodules:

        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=407,69");
        }

        routingTable: Ipv4RoutingTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=45,178");
                //IPForward = IPForward;
                //forwardMulticast = forwardMulticast;
                routingFile = routingFile;
        }
        wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Interface")> like IWirelessInterface {
            parameters:
                @display("p=301.35,379.05;q=queue");
        }

        ext[numExtInterfaces]: <default("ExtInterface")> like IExternalInterface {
            parameters:
                @display("p=217,421,row,10;q=txQueue;i=block/ifcard");
        }

        networkLayer: NetworkLayerNodeBase {
            parameters:
                @display("p=226.8,198.45;q=queue");
        }
        lo0: LoopbackInterface {
            @display("p=78,406");
        }
        App: <default("UdpBasicBurst")> like IApp {
            @display("p=469.35,198.45");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:

        wlan[0].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.radioIn[0];
        //ext[0].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.radioIn[0];
        //lo0.upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.radioIn[0];

}
```

When i put the interface table module in the top level network (GPSSim) instead, i don't get this error but instead i get another error where the interface is already registered which the cause is precisely because i did that, since im telling each instance of satellite to use the same interface table.

I dont' know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the line

```
**.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
```

into:

```
interfaceTableModule = default("interfaceTable");
```

Parameter `interfaceTableModule` should point to the interface table in that node.

Comment: when i do that i get an error in the IDE "no such parameter interfaceTableModule"

Comment: How NED definition of `Satellite` look like?

Comment: i fixed the issue. I just had to use default() for some parameters and absPath for others. Idk why but thanks.